# Querying Azure Log Analytics from VM PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I would like to have my local device query and store data from the same Log Analytics platform that it reports to. All the documentation I have seen shows me how to access/query Log Analytics from the Azure UI & Azure PowerShell, but I have not seen anything on how to query the same data from the Virtual Machine's own PowerShell terminal. Any recommendations? Is this possible, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. To the benefit of anyone who is struggling with the same problem, refer to this:

https://igeorgiev.eu/azure/howto-query-log-analytics-workspace-from-azure-powershell-using-service-principal/

The Log Analytics Workspace context can be retrieved with

```
$workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace
```

After you have retrieved the context and defined a KQL Query, you can query the Log Analytics platform with

```
$QueryResults = Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery -Workspace $Workspace -Query $kqlQuery
```